# Preinstalled Ubuntu os on virtualbox with Win7 host can't start X server

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, xorg, gnome

I just installed virtualbox on my Win7 machine and created a guest virtualbox system image from a existing Ubuntu partition (according to [this guide](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329)). Unfortunetaly the Xserver doesn't start properly and, although I can normally see the grub splash; and later the typical ubuntu 16.04 loading splash - it suddenly disappears, the resolution goes down, and I'm left with a basic shell login. After login I get the message

```
Can't open display "default display"
```

The mentioned tutorial suggested that there may be graphics driver troubles but it didn't mention how to solve them.

Running xrandr only outputs:

```
Can't open display
```

I'd really appreciate some input as I am now completely stuck. The goal here is to have a working gnome-classic desktop (although any working desktop will be fine). Also guest additions are installed and the graphics driver was the proper nVidia driver both on Win7 and the Ubuntu install.

Thanks a bunch,
drinker